# finding possible combination from a given number that starts and ends with common number within the string

Tags: python

**String looks like **

```
num_str = '0110101'
```

Possible number of combination is to be find where the number starts and ends with 1

**for example**

```
11
1101
101
10101
110101
```

Comment: These are not "combinations"; they are "substrings".

Comment: Thank you for sharing your question with us. Would you mind adding what you have tried so far to your current question in order for others to have a better understanding of your problem?

Comment: It isn't clear what the question is. Are you trying to count the substrings or list them? Also -- are you interested in distinct substrings? For example -- `101` occurs twice in your example. Should it be counted twice?

Comment: @ScottHunter yes , wanted to find out substrings :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following works for one interpretation of your question. It works by first finding the indices of the ones, looping over all pairs of those indices, and then slicing:

```
import itertools

num_str = '0110101'
ones = (i for i,d in enumerate(num_str) if d == '1')
for i,j in itertools.combinations(ones,2):
    print(num_str[i:j+1])
```

Output:

```
11
1101
110101
101
10101
101
```

If all you want is the set of such numbers (without any duplicates) then the loop can add numbers to a set rather than print them.

Comment: @ScottHunter Good point. This was why I hedged at the start of the question about "1 interpretation". In any event, it is easy enough to modify the code to eliminate multiplicity.

Comment: Sure, but under what interpretation would code that produces a result different from what the question *explicitly asks for* be said to "work"?

Comment: @JohnColeman thanks for the solution. it solved the purpose. the interpretation was to find every possible combination that starts and ends with 1 out of the given numeric string